# how to hide/show div with classic asp

Tags: asp.net

i just want to hide my div from asp script here is my script:

```
<%
        Dim posted = Request.Form("submit")
        If posted = "Submit" Then
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            '' Customize the following 5 lines with your own information. ''
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Dim Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
            Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
            Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
            Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
            Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
            Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
            Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
            Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "easyweb999@gmail.com"
            Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "easy@123"
            Mail.Configuration.Fields.Update()
            Mail.Subject = "Software Download"
            Mail.From = "easyweb999@gmail.com"
            Mail.To = Request.Form("v_email") & "," & "easyweb999@gmail.com"
            Dim link As String
            Select Case Request.Form("software")
                Case "EasyOfficeDemoSetup"
                    link = "Set Download Link"
                Case "EasyVATDemoSetup"
                    link = "Set Download Link"
            End Select
            Mail.HTMLBody = "Name : " & Request.Form("v_contact") & "<br/><br/>" & "Company Name : " & Request.Form("vco_name") & "<br/><br/>" & "Address : " & Request.Form("v_address") & "<br/><br/>" & "City : " & Request.Form("v_city") & "<br/><br/>" & "Zip Code : " & Request.Form("zip_code") & "<br/><br/>" & "State : " & Request.Form("state") & "<br/><br/>" & "Country : " & Request.Form("v_country") & "<br/><br/>" & "Telephone No : " & Request.Form("v_phone") & "<br/><br/>" & "Mobile No : " & Request.Form("mobile") & "<br/><br/>" & "Email : " & Request.Form("v_email") & "<br/><br/>" & "Software Download : " & link & "<br/><br/>" & "Remark : " & Request.Form("remark")
            Mail.Send()
            Dim vErr = Err.Description
            If vErr <> "" Then
                Response.Write(vErr & "<br><br>There was an error on this page.")
            Else
                //this is div with id that i want to show/hide
                demo1.Visible = False
                success.Visible = True
                'Response.Write("Thank you, your message has been sent.")
            End If
            Mail = Nothing
        End If
%>
```

here i just place two div with id demo1 and success with runat="server" so i can access this div from asp script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery:

$('#div_id').show() or $('#div_id').hide()

Or CSS:

.hidden{display:none}

Comment: is that possible with classic asp. how ever demo1.Visible=False i can put that but no effect occurs from View side.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this..

```
<%


    Dim mydiv1, mydiv2

    If (condition) Then
       mydiv1 = "visible"
       mydiv2 = "hidden"
    Else
       mydiv1 = "hidden"
       mydiv2 = "visable"
    End IF

    %>

    <div id="divMyID1" style="visibility:<%=mydiv2%>;">Test1</div>
    <div id="divMyID2" style="visibility:<%=mydiv1%>;"> Test2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### For this just try below code:

```html
For this just try below code:


  <div id="dvshowitem" class="mid-line" style="display:<%=divstyle%>"></div>

  <%
     Dim Itemcount,divstyle
      if Itemcount<6 then
       divstyle ="none"
        else
       divstyle ="block"
        end if
%>

Here 'Itemcount' is number of items and 'dvshowitem' will be hide if item count is less than 6.
```